# Accessing logged in user roles and include in page source

Tags: acumatica

We are intergrating an external JavaScript application into Acumatica and we have a need to be able to access the logged in users authorization / user access roles. Our thought is that if we can write the logged in users access roles to the page source as global scope variables our JavaScript app can handle the rest, but we are a bit challenged in figuring out how to do that. We know we can write the roles to the trace screen, but that doesn't help as we need it literally in the page source for this to work (ideally the page source and not the DOM - but we can look into if the DOM could work too).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The page source in ASP.Net is a ASPX.CS file that resides on the server, I doubt your JavaScript can hook into that. The communication from the server to the UI layer is a template engine.

You define the fields in the ASPX file and these template fields are populated with the DataViews current record. The minified JavaScript that is in the page runs that templating engine.

You can't simply generate dynamic HTML or access the JavaScript side of things from the server. So having fields values in the DOM is probably your best bet. You can make the controls invisible if required.

Example to read UI control values using JavaScript:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/FormDetail.master" %>
<asp:content id="cont1" contentplaceholderid="phDS" runat="Server">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            // Fetch a value from UI control
            var control = px_alls["edControlID"];
            var value = control.getValue();
        });         
    </script>

    [...]

</asp:content>
```